# Change overlay title background width in Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

How can I change the overlay title background `width` in Fancybox 2 to the image width? I tried to change in `CSS` the `.fancybox-title-overlay-wrap` width to 100%, but this isn't good.

here is the code:

```
.fancybox-title-overlay-wrap {
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Any example, code or link will help.

Comment: to be honest, I have never seen the `.fancybox-title-overlay-wrap` selector: am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Fancybox title's size is calculated dynamically so you cannot set the `width` with css because the value will be overwritten anyways. You would need to calculate the the `width` of the current image and set the `title` size accordingly, using a callback.

If the `title type` is the default `float`, then use something like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function() {
        var imageWidth = $(".fancybox-image").width();
        $(".fancybox-title-float-wrap .child").css({
            "width": imageWidth
        });
    }
});​
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hEDUp/)**

On the other hand, if the `title type` is `over`, then it's a bit more complex but you could do :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: "over"
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        var imageWidth = $(".fancybox-image").width();
        $(".fancybox-title-over-wrap").css({
            "width": imageWidth,
            "paddingLeft": 0,
            "paddingRight": 0,
            "textAlign": "center"
        });
    }
});​
```

See this other **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bB2ST/)**

Comment: **+1** Excellent Answer! I always prefer using a callback for custom CSS modifications which allows the original Fancybox Titlebar to operate as intended, when required. I like your 2nd fiddle as a Titlebar Overlay... nice!  Here's your [**first jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B3PbY/1/) tweaked. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

### [**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv9cN/)

Whenever I see a question about how to mod a plugins CSS, I quickly turn to Firefox and it's unique CSS Live editing capabilities.

Launching a jsFiddle with Fancybox images, I hover over the Fancybox Title area and right mouse-click to choose **Inspect Element**. Once I see the **Inspector Panel**, I then press the 2nd icon from the Left Side to pop-up the HTML Panel to look at the DOM layout of elements on the webpage.

Here, in the general Title area, I do see classname `.fancybox-title` as the element to target. I then add-in an extra **attribute** for that style to make `width` `100%`except it didn't change the visual width of the black Title bar.

However, I do see a `span` with the actual Title text with classname of `child`. I `Inspect` that and give it also a value of `100%` and the full width of the Title bar is realized, but looks much better at `93%` percent since the curved black corners add to the overall visual width.

It's then noticed that when text is too long, it exceeds outside the Fancybox full `width` title area. I then understand that ***two settings are needed***. I change that `93%` `width` on `.fancybox-title` to `auto` and the second setting is a `min-width` with value of `93%` for `.fancybox-title .child` selector.

**CSS:**

```css
.fancybox-title {
  width: 100%;
}

.fancybox-title .child {
  width: auto;    /* Here we define width as auto, so it's always the correct size for overflowing Title text. */
  min-width: 93%; /* When text is not flowing over, the black Title bar is 93% of Fancybox width. */
}
```

For certain CSS problems that are buggy, I use **Firefox 3D View** which allows you to ***rotate and zoom*** the stage, to pick at the CSS as **layers**. You'll see that button on the right side.